# Search for user in array from textarea but only after entering a certain character Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a textarea like so..

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="message" id="commentBox" placeholder="Add your comment here..."></textarea>
```

and I have a list that pulls in users from an external api like so..

```
<div class="mention-container">
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        user.name
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and the users array is like so..

```
users = [
    {
        name: steve,
        id: 47 
    },
    {
        name: james,
        id: 41
    },
    {
        name: guy,
        id: 44 
    },
    {
        name: troy,
        id: 32 
    }
]
```

now Ive created a custom @mention system where I listen out for when a user types in @ in the text area and then it shows the list of users

so this is my function

```
listenForMention(): void {
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const mentionSelect = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.mention-container');
const atKeyCode = 50;
const spaceCharacter = ' ';
const shiftKeyCode = 16;
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === shiftKeyCode) {
    return; // ignore shift key presses
  }
  if (
     // '@' is first character in textarea OR
    event.keyCode === atKeyCode &&
    // the character before the '@' is a space
    (textarea.selectionStart === 1 || textarea.value[textarea.selectionStart - 2] === spaceCharacter)
  ) {
    // Show mention container
    mentionSelect.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

}

so what its doing is listening for the `@` symbol and then It displays the full list of users, but what I want to do is after a user has typed in `@` then start searching through the users in the list and removing users from the array so if I type in `st` I only want `steve` to be shown in the list,

now Ive found a few search filter plugins for angular like so..
[ng2-filter-search](https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter#readme) but they use ngModel and pipes on an input.. how can I create something similar in a text area and only after a user has typed an @symbol and then turned off when the user has selected the user they wish to select. From research on my own a pipe seems to be the best way to do this but I cant figure out how I can start a filter in a textarea only after entering @

**EDIT**

Im thinking something along the lines of

pipe.ts

```
if(previous character === '@') {
   start filtering..
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `angular-mentions` package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-mentions

You can pass users to textarea like this:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="message" [mention]="users" id="commentBox" placeholder="Add your comment here..."></textarea>
```